# issue in redirecting user to home page django

Tags: django, authentication, http-redirect

When I try to login, it does not reedirect me to home page. instead, it shows me an error
the url should be http://127.0.0.1:8000/  it shows http://127.0.0.1:8000/login
I tried to user both function and path names

**urls.py**

```
app_name = "accounts"

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home,name="home"),
    path('register/',views.register, name='register'),
    path('login/',views.loginPage, name='login')]
```

**views.py**

```
def loginPage(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(request,username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request,user)
            return redirect('home')
    return render(request,'accounts/login.html')
```

**Error**

```
NoReverseMatch at /login/
Reverse for 'home' not found. 'home' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/
Django Version: 3.0.4
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'home' not found. 'home' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Exception Location: C:\Users\Mahmoud Ishag\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 677
```

Comment: Change `home` to `accounts:home`

Answer (score 0):

In views.py the url name works differently to when in template.

You can try to change `return redirect('home')` to `return redirect('')` or `return redirect('/')`, depends on how you defined the URL in `path('', views.home, name="home")`.